# angular 1.x array push with multiple variables via html form

Tags: angularjs

I would like to push text via a html form in my array. The problem is that every tutorial I habe seen only explains how I add one variable.

My Array:
(this is that I mean)

```
$scope.titles = [{
  title: 'New Divide',
  artist: 'Linkin Park',
  album: 'New Divide',
  genre: 'Rock',
  cover: 'new-divide.jpg',
  titleLength: '4:28',
  file: 'test'
}];
```

My html form:

```
<form ng-submit="musicController.addMusic(musicController.titles, musicController.artist, musicController.album, musicController.genre, musicController.titleLength, musicController.cover, musicController.file)">
        <input ng-model="musicController.title" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.artist" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.album" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.genre" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.titleLength" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.cover" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.file" type="text" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the ng-model for each of your inputs as an object property. That way they will all be grouped together in one object so you won't have to push each individual value:

```
<form ng-submit="musicController.addMusic(musicController.record)">
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.title" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.artist" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.album" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.genre" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.titleLength" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.cover" type="text" />
        <input ng-model="musicController.record.file" type="text" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
```

Just to clarify, your `addMusic` function should look something like the following:

```
$scope.addMusic = function(record) {
    $scope.titles.push(record);
};
```